# Will application layer cache the underlying connection when connected using domain?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

```
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:mysql://exmaple.com:3306/mysql", "root", "****"
);
```

How this connection will be cached ? will app layer has the actual IP to which it resolves or every-time load balancer will resolve to which node it should connect to ?

say example.com points to 2 IPs (machine 1 & machine 2) and load balancer has 30 mins as persistence time.

Comment: The connection isn't cached. Why do you think it would be? Or you need to be more explicit in what you're asking (because you're asking about connections being cached and IP addresses being cached which are two entirely different things!).

Comment: have created connection using above jdbc method and storing it in queue. Would like to know how the connection will be stored , will dns resolve everytime or actual ip which handled the request when connection created will be used ?

Comment: You mean for an existing connection? The connection establishes a TCP/IP socket connection and uses that until it is closed, so it only needs to resolve the host to IP address once per connection, and your OS itself has a cache to service DNS resolution.

Comment: As an aside, using a queue to store connections sounds like a homemade connection pool. Don't do that, use an existing connection pool library like HikariCP, Apache DBCP or C3P0.